# C# - reverse duplicates for "var"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

There are two highly rated by search engines questions discussing what "var" means in C#. Currently "What does var mean in C#" is duplicate of "Use of var keyword in C#" even if later is clearly off-topic as it is essentially "why I should even use that syntax - discuss/flame" (and has historical lock).

Are there any objections to reverse duplicates making "What does var mean in C#" to be the main one? Alternatively if you know of better duplicate - let's use it. I really don't like clearly off-topic question used as a duplicate target...

As one possible objection I can see that we can use "Use of var keyword in C#" as duplicate target to all "should I use implicit or explicit type declaration" types of post-your-opinion questions... but that should be still fine if it is itself closed as duplicate.

1. [What does "var" mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307467/what-does-var-mean-in-c)
2. [Use of var keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp)

If there are no strong objections in two days I'll request moderator attention to reverse the duplicate chain as currently "use of var keyword" one has historic lock (which is appropriate to the question itself).

Comment: My only question is.... why? What's the point in changing it besides you don't like off-topic questions being dupe targets?

Comment: @NickAthePopcornKing one - duplicates are somewhat "this is the best question/answers to your question we have on the site" - pointing to off-topic question is strange... sometimes it is not possible to ask on-topic question about a given subject altogether but I don't think it is case here. Another - you can't maintain (edit/vote) locked question (and I don't want to see that style discussion to be unlocked).

Comment: Personally I don't regard them as duplicates and will vote to reopen.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's better reasoning that I can't disagree with :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't regard these as duplicates, although they are related.

*(I've arbitrarily assigned them names post 1 and 2 for discussion)*

#### Post 1

[What does "var" mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307467/what-does-var-mean-in-c) is a reasonable and on topic question for the site and it's current scope.

#### Post 2

[Use of var keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp) is largely opinion based in its current form, however an edit of how it is worded could bring it within the question scope of the site. It is still a different question from the other one. It discusses the ins and out of using "var" where the first question simple asks what "var" means.

I've voted to reopen the first post, as it's not a duplicate of the second. I don't think the second should be closed as a duplicate of the first either.

Comment: Realistically I can't see an edit that can bring "list why you like `var`" question to be on topic without invalidating all hundreds answers there (ignoring the historical lock part)... But I see your point that maybe they should not be duplicates...